# Can't open more than 28234 sockets?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm writing a network service and I'm aiming for high concurrency. For some reason, when I try to connect to the 28,234th socket I get:

```
[Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

The client is written in python and the server side is written in haskell. I'm running this on ubuntu 11.04, and:

```
$ ulimit -n
1048576
```

How can I overcome this limitation?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need that many sockets?

Comment: You are trying to listen on more than 28000 simultaneously? You will simply run out of ports.

Comment: `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_DGRAM`?

Comment: Are you trying to create 30000 clients connecting _from_ the same system?  Do you consider that a realistic use case?

Comment: @Ikke, I'm going to create a high-performance websocket server. @Sven, that is probably the answer. Thank you. @Neil, actually, I consider myself primarily a C programmer and I understand the problems surrounding high concurrency very well. Please don't be so presumptuous in the future. @Turbo J, SOCK_STREAM. @Nemo, no, this is for the purposes of benchmarking, I don't happen to have 100,000 spare machines that I can do a test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual workaround is to create additional IP addresses on the host, each IP will gain you an additional ephemeral port range as per dan_waterworth's answer as long as you bind the socket to the interface.

Microsoft have a discussion on the topic here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150670(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The ephemeral port range set in:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
```

Prevents you from creating more connections.

Comment: Which is a bit odd as `28232 < 28284`.

Comment: @Steve-o, the last one fails and the range is probably inclusive.

Comment: oh it's a typo with the question as you write both 84 and 34.